# Number of SPP port by bluetoothapis.h

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth

How I can get number virtual com port for device connected via Bluetooth in SPP mode?
I am use bluetoothapis.h.

Now I can pair with Device via bluetooth with bluetoothapis.h.
Get list of visible devices.
But I cannot figure out how get number of virtual port for bluetooth device.
There are virtual com ports in device manager.

I use Win7. Please help figure out.

Comment: You can not do it with standard Bluetooth API.

Comment: Okey, what should I do for resolve this?

Comment: You should you SetupAPI (or CFGMGR API) toherther with Registry to find which port is for which device.

Comment: I am sorry, but what is "SetupAPI (or CFGMGR API)"? And where in Registry stores that info?

Comment: [SetupAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/setupapi). [Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/cfgmgr32/). Unfortunately I can not say the Registry keys because it is private information. We spent time to find it out. If I could I posted it as an answer, not as the comment.

Comment: Could we continue in private chat?

Comment: Sure, why not..

Comment: I cannot to create prvate chat here.